# How to merge two similar queries working based on if-else into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query like below (SQL Server 2008):

```
if (@checkValue = 1) 
begin

  select *
  from table1 t
  inner join table2 t2 on t.Id = t2.t_Id
                      and DATEDIFF(hour,t2.Start,t.Start) < 24

end
else 
begin

  select *
  from table1 t
  inner join table2 t2 on t.Id = t2.t_Id
                       and Convert(Date, t.Start) = Convert(Date,t2.Start) 

end
```

I am not happy with this query since I basically duplicated the main query and made a slight change. I am looking for a more professional way, like merging the queries into 1 by adding a where clause maybe. I appreciate if someone helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with the conditions specified in a `where` clause.

```
select *
from table1 t
inner join table2 t2 on t.Id = t2.t_Id
where (@checkValue = 1 AND DATEDIFF(hour,t2.Start,t.Start) < 24)
or (@checkValue <> 1 AND Convert(Date, t.Start) = Convert(Date,t2.Start))
```